# How to create OpenGL 3.0 context using Pyglet

Tags: python, opengl, py2exe, opengl-3, pyglet

I'd like to make use of OpenGL 3.0 features (framebuffer objects, 2D texture array), but the default OpenGL context created by Pyglet does not support these.

In the Pyglet source there is the following example: https://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/browse/examples/opengl_3.py

Sadly, this example was last edited in 2008 and no longer seems to work (`get_info()` is not a context method anymore), and even the `major_version` and `minor_version` arguments don't seem to be used anymore.

What did work however, was using PyOpenGL in combination with Pyglet. Is this the only way to get access to OpenGL 3.0+? Whatever method I end up using, it has to work with Py2exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pyglet` should automatically create the highest version context it can. Does your hardware/drivers support OpenGL 3?

```
$ python -c "from pyglet.window import Window; print(Window().context.get_info
().get_version())"
4.2.0
```

`major_version` and `minor_version` seem to work as well:

```
$ python -c "from pyglet.window import Window; \
             from pyglet.gl import Config; \
             print(Window(config=Config(major_version=3, minor_version=2))\
                     .context.get_info().get_version())"
3.2.0
```

`get_info` is [still a Context method](https://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/browse/pyglet/gl/base.py#382). What pyglet do you use?

`get_info` wasn't a Context method before pyglet 1.2, and there is no OpenGL 3 example with pyglet 1.1.

You should use pyglet 1.2 alpha (or the latest source).

Comment: I was using the current release (1.1.4) of Pyglet, and have now upgraded to 1.2, which has solved my problem (it creates an OpenGL 3.3 context for me). Thanks!